# Loop Array and match a word within an array element (containing all strings) and if it matches, paste that element into another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

VBA (Excel)

New to Arrays. I have bible verses in Column A, verse references in Column B

I want to match a word, say "wisdom", and if the array element contains a match within the string then say array(i,1) & array(i,2) gets pasted into another worksheet.

I have found multiple examples but nothing worked until I finally found some code using "INSTR" that I was able to adapt.

Unfortunately, the code sometimes works and other times does not when looping through the array and checking each element.  The funny thing is that if I create another worksheet with a list of topics, I can incorporate another array for that list, and use the two together flawlessly.  I want the first code below to work 100% of the time.`

```
Sub TopicInput()
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, 
LastColLetter As String
Dim VerseArray() As Variant, i As Long
Dim SourceWS As Worksheet, Topic As String

LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.count     'FIND # of LAST Row with DATA
LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Columns.count  'FIND # of LAST Column with DATA
LastColLetter = Split(Cells(1, 
LastCol).Address, "$")(1)                       'CHANGE # to Actual LETTER of COLUMN

Topic = InputBox("Enter Topic or Topic...")

Set SourceWS = Sheets("Proverbs")
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheet.count)).Name = Topic
sourceWS.activate

VerseArray = Range("a1:" & LastColLetter & LastRow)   'inputs data automatically into array
x=0
For i = LBound(VerseArray) To UBound(VerseArray)
    If InStr(1, VerseArray(i, 1), Topic, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then   ' does element contain the word in variable Topic 
    x=x+1: Sheets(Topic).select        
    Sheets(Topic).Range("A" & x).Value = VerseArray(i, 1)
    Sheets(Topic).Range("B" & x).Value = VerseArray(i, 2)
    End If
    
    Debug.Print i, VerseArray(i, 1)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried multiple times to edit the post, but keep getting error message of code not indented even when adding spaces to each line.  so, I cannot post the finished code